# Mysql query not return correctly

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having problem with these result. I have been trying but no luck.

jobs table

```
   id, title ... all details
    1, title1,...
    2, title2,...
    3, title3,...
    4, title4,...
```

job_user table

```
id,id_job,id_user
1,1,1
2,2,3
3,3,3
4,4,4
```

following_job table

```
id,id_job,id_user
1, 1, 3
```

So basically, user 3 has 2 jobs (2,3), and he follows job 1 of user 1. so, if i login as user 3, i would like to get all details jobs of user <> 3 (just the requirement that i need to do). i would get the result

```
id,id_job,id_user
    1,1,1 
    4,4,4
```

My goal results would be :

```
id,title..., following_id
        1,title1,...,1
        4,title4,...,0
```

the following_id will be added as result above, since user 3 followed id_job 1 so its following_id = 1 else = 0. And id_job 1,4 will joined with jobs table to get details about it : title ...

I am doing the follow/unfollow job functionality

Thanks all

Comment: This appears to be a simple join between all 3 tables. what have you tried?;

Comment: @xQbert thanks for your response. I have tried something similar to JNevill suggestion but in different order of query. I will try following his suggestion to see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... it seems like you want something like:

```
SELECT
    jobs.id,
    jobs.title,
    jobs....,
    CASE WHEN following_job.id_user = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as following_job
FROM
    jobs
    INNER JOIN job_user ON job.id = job_user.id_job
    LEFT OUTER JOIN JOIN following_job on job.id = following_job.id_job
WHERE
    job_user.id_user <> 3;
```

Joining all three tables according to your schema. Filtering via the `WHERE` clause to insure that no jobs that are no jobs that user `3` has. And then a CASE (or `IF()`) statement to flag the job as followed by user `3`.

Comment: Inner join on following_job will eliminate all but ID_USER 3 and then the where clause eliminates it right so... No records returned?

Comment: I think in Left Joins and then write INNER JOINs because I'm special. I have fixed it. :/

Comment: I like special people they make me smile :P

Comment: @JNevill Thank you. let me try.  to see if that work. I have been thinking it in a wrong way of combining those 3 tables

Comment: @JNevill I got it work. Thanks a lot. Marked as the answer.